Arranging two types of objects with conditions in a row

Nikhil, Bartek, and Eshaan have 3, 3, and 2 colored shirts: Nikhil’s
are red, Bartek’s are white, and Eshaan’s shirts are blue. Some of
these shirts have flags. Nikhil and Eshaan each have one such shirt
and Bartek has two. They want to arrange their shirts so all of each
person’s shirts are together, and for each flag shirt, there is
another flag shirt at most one position away from it. How many ways
can they arrange their shirts to satisfy these conditions? The color
and presence (or lack) of a flag are the only distinguishing factors
of a shirt. (JHMMC 2022 R1, 7th grade #30)

Official Solution: If Nikhil’s shirts are in the middle, then Nikhil’s flag shirt must be within 2 of Eshaan’s flag shirt since they both only have one. Possible flag positions for each person below, left to right(Eshaan, Nikhil, Bartek)
$$\_\,\_\,F\ |\ \_\,F\,\_\,\_\ |\ F\,F\,\_\,\_\,\_$$
There are 3 ways to arrange Nikhil and Eshaan’s flag shirts and 7 ways to arrange Bartek’s shirts. So, in this case, there’s 3 · 2 · 7 = 42 ways to arrange the shirts, since Bartek could be on the left. (Solution continues...)
I am getting ${3\choose2} = 3$ ways of arranging Bartek's shirts becuse of which there are three shirts, and two of those have flags. What am I missing?

Based off of the official solution which says $$\_\,\_\,F\ |\ \_\,F\,\_\,\_\ |\ F\,F\,\_\,\_\,\_$$ are possible positions, I think the official question is poorly written and it should actually say they have $3$, $3$ and $2$ non-flag shirts (or equivalently $4$, $5$ and $3$ shirts). Then there are $\binom{5}{2}=10$ ways to arrange Bartek's shirts. But three of them ($F---F$, $F--F-$ and $-F--F$) break the rule, so there are 7 ways that follow the rule.
